# 1:1 Relationship Queries

Tags: sql, report, stimulsoft

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction for what I am trying to do, sorry if this is worded horribly.

I have two tables WorkOrders and WorkOrderAssets, WorkOrders essentially is the header record for a ticket that gets created within our system. WorkOrderAssets is an item record table that can be attached to a WorkOrder record. Once WorkOrder record can have an unlimited number of Assets attached. However I am trying to build a report that looks for WorkOrders that only have one WorkOrderAssets record attached to it.

What is the best way to exclude 1 to many records and only pull when there is a 1:1? The reporting language is stimulsoft but the query is mostly made up of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be this simple?  I only had Microsoft SQL handy, but this is how I would do it.  I created sample tables to test.

```
insert WorkOrders(WorkOrderId)
values (1), (2), (3), (4)

create table WorkOrderAssets (WorkOrderAssetId int, WorkOrderId int)
insert WorkOrderAssets (WorkOrderAssetId, WorkOrderId)
values (11,1), (12,1), (13,1), (21,2), (31,3), (41,4), (42,4)

select wo.WorkOrderId
from WorkOrders as wo
    join WorkOrderAssets as wa on wa.WorkOrderId = wo.WorkOrderId
group by wo.WorkOrderId
having count(wa.WorkOrderAssetId) = 1
```

Results:

```
WorkOrderId
2
3
```

Comment: Yes it totally could! I completely forgot about the count command. Thank you so much!